# Change text when someone click but after sometime

Tags: javascript, java, android, xml, android-studio

i want to change the text when someone click a button button after some time

for example : someone click on a button "new button" but when someone click on a the text doesn't change after 10 or 12 hours it changes the text.

how can i do that?

also whensome one click on a button it redirect to url.

Answer (score 0):

try this for changing text after some time:

```
 button.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener(){


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

Timer timer=new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                text.settext("What do you want");
            }
        },when);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks the button save the time using `SharedPreferences`.

```java
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Get current time
                    Date currentDate = new Date();

                    // Save time
                    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("saveddata.xml", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putLong("savedtime", currentDate.getTime());
                    editor.commit();
                }
            });
```

Each time when the activity starts check the time difference.

```java
// Get date from pref
Date oldDate = new Date(prefs.getLong("savedtime", 0));

// Compare dates
// 43200000ms is 12hrs
if (currentDate.getTime() - oldDate.getTime() > 43200000) {
    button.setText("Text changed!");
}
```

***You can't use `TimerTask`, since it will be destroyed if your activity is killed by the system. (Very likely to happen in 12 hours)***

To answer your second question, you can create an `ACTION_VIEW` intent to open a URL:

```java
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.example.com"));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```